# Running batchfile admin to set envirnment var

Tags: batch-file

I am running into an issue here on Windows 10. I am trying to set an environment variable within the batch file using a `for ... in ... do`, but it never finds the file folder I am looking for.

example:

```
cd \temp
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad somefolder*') do set somefolder=%%a
cd \temp\%somefolder%\microsoft
```

When run as an administrator I will get an error: `file not found`. When run as non-admin it functions properly. This can only be run as a batch while using DISM.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. I've edited your question to format the code to make it easier to read. Once the edit appears, please confirm that I didn't inadvertently change the code.

Comment: Does the name of the folder you are searching really begin with `somefolder`? and is it placed in the `temp` directory of the root directory of the current drive (whatever it is)?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "somefolder" is a relative folder path.

When running as admin, you have a different default directory. If you use an absolute path, it should work fine.

Comment: actually %somefolder% is an absolute path as the folder is present as I made the folder. The C:\temp is off the root which shows it's absolute.I am only searching for the folder name as it changes monthly.

Comment: When you are running under DISM, is \temp a valid way to refer to c:\temp? Have you tried "cd /d c:\temp"?

Comment: Check out the last comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872799/dism-fails-in-bat-but-runs-fine-from-command-prompt. I'm not sure how you are invoking this script but it seems like it might help.

Comment: iPaulo you hit the nail on the head by referencing the other article. This loop is no functioning properly.

Comment: That's good. Did it help though? :) Are you using this loop in a similar way, calling DISM to mount the directory you are trying to loop through? It might be useful to post more of your script to see the context.